# Interface Builder UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uidatepicker

is there a way to set the UIDatepicker to minute and seconds versus Hour and Minute

*edit* I ended up adding my own UIPicker class, and creating the value and label myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any builtin way to do this in the SDK. Try just subclassing UIPickerView and you should end up with basically the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the help for UICatalog it has full examples of pickers and how to make you own custom picker.

There is no option to show minutes seconds according to the API documentation.